# cannot insert to another table after register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

i want to insert into `userbio` after register here is my register `RegisterController`

```
   protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $databio = new ModelBio();
        $maxbio =  $databio->getMaxbioId();
       // die(  $maxbio );

        return User::create([
            'username'  => $data['username'],
            'email'     => $data['email'],
            'biodataId' =>   $maxbio,
            'password'  => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        return Biodata::create([
            'biodataId' =>   $maxbio,
            'fullname'  => $data['fullname']
        ]);

    }
```

It creates new record for `Users`. But, there is a problem i cant insert into `usersbio`, I can't find any error message there . Btw `RegisterController` is from laravel auth.  here is my `Biodata`

```
class Biodata extends Model 
{
    //

    protected $primaryKey = 'biodataId';
    protected $table = "usersbio";
    public $incrementing = false;

   protected $fillable = [
     'biodataId','address','fullname','remarks'
    ];

    static function getMaxbioId(){

         $max = Biodata::max('biodataId');
        if($max == ""){
            return "BIO-0001";
        }else{

            $number = substr($max, 4);
            return 'BIO-' . sprintf('%04d', intval($number) + 1);

        }
    }

}
```

how can i fix it ? thanks in advance

Comment: You do know what `return` does, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not write `return` while creating User. It actually returns from there and no further code will be executed of the function.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $databio = new ModelBio();
    $maxbio =  $databio->getMaxbioId();
   // die(  $maxbio );

    User::create([            // Removed `return` from here
        'username'  => $data['username'],
        'email'     => $data['email'],
        'biodataId' =>   $maxbio,
        'password'  => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    return Biodata::create([
        'biodataId' =>   $maxbio,
        'fullname'  => $data['fullname']
    ]);

}
```

Comment: whoaaa. thats why .btw, is it fine if i do something like this . `User::create([...]); Biodata::create([...]); return`

Comment: You better write `return true;`